# Drag and drop from Photos.app to Photoshop

Tags: macos, photos.app, adobe-photoshop

I can't seem to drag-and-drop photos from the Photos application into Photoshop, I could do this with iPhoto... How do I edit them in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop does not seem to be possible. You can export the original to your desktop and then open with photoshop or another app.

[How to export to desktop.](http://www.imore.com/how-use-external-editor-photos-os-x)

Comment: but... why? this should be any easy fix for the app. i don't want to wast space on duplicate images :(

Comment: I agree. Simple to implement but not sure why apple decided not to.